# Prove the following using the Frenet Serret formulae

Tags: differential-geometry

Let (c) be a parametrically defined canonical curve, and ({t, n, b}) be the Frenet frame. Show that there exists a vector $\vec{v}$ such that the following relationships hold:
[
\begin{align*}
    \vec{t}' &= \vec{v} \times \vec{t} \\
    \vec{n}' &= \vec{v} \times \vec{n} \\
    \vec{b}' &= \vec{v} \times \vec{b}
\end{align*}
]

I tried writing an explanation for the first 2 but I am not sure it is mathematically correct.

For the first relationship, $t' = \vec{v} \times \vec{t}$, we can use the definition of the Frenet frame, which tells us that $t'$ is proportional to $\vec{n}$. Thus, we can write $t' = \kappa \vec{n}$, where $\kappa$ is a constant of proportionality. Consequently, we have a direct relationship between $t'$ and $\vec{n}$.

For the second relationship, $n' = \vec{v} \times \vec{n}$, we can once again use the definition of the Frenet frame for $n'$, given as $n' = -\kappa \vec{t} + \tau \vec{b}$. We observe that the left-hand side of this equation, $-\kappa \vec{t}$, is proportional to $\vec{t}$, and the right-hand side, $\tau \vec{b}$, is proportional to $\vec{b}$. Therefore, we can express $n' = v \vec{t} + w \vec{b}$, where $v$ and $w$ are constants of proportionality. Now, $\vec{v} \times \vec{n}$ is proportional to $\vec{b}$, which means the second relationship is satisfied with $v = w$.

Comment: See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.01082.pdf).

Comment: I think the article @JeanMarie linked will confuse a beginning student. Set $v=\alpha t+\beta n+\gamma b$ and write out the three equations.